# Copy files and directory tree for filesize in specified range

Tags: shell-script, find, file-copy

I would like to make a small script copying files from different directories example `/pp/01` `/pp/02/` etc... to another destination with the same directory design. But only those files within the directory with a size larger than 88MB but smaller than 93MB...

I would use a for loop and the find function. Are there more efficient ways? And how can I implement the find function exactly.

Comment: `rsync` has options `--max-size` and `--min-size`. `find` has the option `-size` which could be issued twice.

Comment: @MattBianco Wouldn't you like to add an answer using your `rsync` proposal? I think that would be the shortest code and probably a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 5):

This command:

```
rsync -a --min-size 88m --max-size 93m pp /new_destination/
```

copies the structure from `pp` to `/new_destination`, but only files that are at least 88 MB and at most 93 MB in size.

Add more source directory trees before the final destination specifier if you like, such as:

```
rsync -a --min-size 88m --max-size 93m pp/01 pp/02 /target/
```

If you add a trailing slash to the source specification (`pp/` as opposed to `pp`), `rsync` will not create that directory in the target.

In other words:`pp` in my first example, results in `/new_destination/pp/01/...`, whilst this:

```
rsync -a --min-size 88m --max-size 93m pp/ /new_destination/
```

instead results in `/new_destination/01/...`, `/new_destination/02/...`.

The `-a` flag to `rsync` means "archive" which recurses directories, preserves metadata on the files, such as permissions and timestamps. (It is a convenience option that equals `-rlptgoD` which is a very popular combination of options).

Comment: This is the one really works

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$ find /file/location/ -type f -size +88M -size -93M \
    -exec cp {} /new/location/ \;`
```

This command will find only files that are larger that 88MB and smaller than 93MB. It will then copy each of the files to `/new/location`.

When it comes to keeping the directory structure it becomes a little harder. I would solve this problem like this:

```
$ cd /pp
$ find . -type f -size +88M -size -93M -exec cp \
    --parents {} /new/location/pp \;
```

This will make `find` return file paths that look like `01/myfile`, `02/myfile` on so on. The parent flag on `cp` makes it append a slash + the specified name of the source file.

Example: `find` finds a file that matches and outputs "02/myfile". `cp` moves this file to `/new/location/pp/02/myfile`, creating any directories that are needed.

Comment: I think that this command will not keep the directory structure, right?

Comment: You are correct. I am not 100% on what you mean but I will try to update my answer.

Comment: There. This might not be the most elegant solution, but (assuming I understood your problem correctly) it should work.

Comment: Note that the `M` suffix assumes a GNU or FreeBSD `find`. It also means that files of size 92.1MiB won't be included (because 92.1 is rounded up (to 93) before comparing with 93, so excluded as not less than 93).

Comment: The `--parents` assumes a GNU `cp`.

Comment: Using `find *` instead of `find .` means that hidden files and dirs in the current directory (and in the current directory only) will be omitted, and that may cause the command to fail if there are files whose name starts with `-` or match `find` predicates.

Comment: Why the second paragraph of command copied a lots of empty file for me?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming file and directory names don't contain newline characters, POSIXly:

```
cd /path/to/src/ &&
  find . -type f -size -"$((93 * 1024 * 1024))c" \
                 -size +"$((88 * 1024 * 1024))c" |
    pax -rw /path/to/dst/
```

Comment: I think you might be able to handle `\n`ewlines even if you did `find ... -exec sh -c 'pax -rw "$@"' -- \{\} +` I dunno if I've got that right, but I think it's close. I'm just looking over that `pax` spec for the first time and it specifically says that newlines can be handled by reading them in on the command line and that *A pathname of a file to be copied or archived* is an *operand [that] shall be supported...* I think you'd have to use `-s` to edit out the newline though before archiving or something...

Answer (score 1):

To copy files with size in a range from "minimum" to "maximum", and re-create the directory structure, use something like this

```
MINSIZE=3k  
MAXSIZE=10k  
cd /source/dir && \
   find . -type f -size "+$MINSIZE" -size "-$MAXSIZE" | cpio -pvdm /target/path
```

`cpio` options

- `-p` "Pass-though" mode, each file listed is copied to the specified directory
- `-v` "Verbose", can be omitted, or to make a dot for every file just to have a visual clue about the progress, use `-V` in stead.
- `-d` "Create directories as needed"
- `-m`  "Preserve the Mode" (permissions, ownership)

Comment: I would recommend joining the `cd` and `find` commands into one line with `&&` in case the `cd` fails for any reason:
`cd /source/path && find . -type f ... | cpio -p... /abs/target/path`